How much extra stack space should I reserve for MS-DOS and interrupts?
When I write a program for MS-DOS, and I know at most how many bytes of stack space my program needs, then how many extra bytes of additional stack space should I reserve (in the assembly source code of my program) for MS-DOS and interrupts?
There is the similar question In MS-DOS, how much stack do I need to make an int21 call? , but it's about calling int 21h from a 32-bit DOS program with DPMI. I'm asking about a 16-bit DOS programs. My program is not using DPMI, but I'd like to make it work on DOS systems and emulations where other programs may be using DPMI, and a couple of TSRs are also active. My program is not a TSR, and it isn't hooking any interrupts.
I'm hoping for an answer close to 80 bytes, preferably backed by some evidence or documentation. Just saying that 256 bytes or 512 bytes should be enough (without evidence or documentation) is not useful, I already know that.

A lot of interrupt drivers (typically installed by TSRs but perhaps also other device drivers) rely upon the application stack, rather than switching to their own stack on entry, and some of them had a worst-case stack usage of over 100 bytes.  An application that used all but 80 bytes of the stack would probably work most of the time, but be incompatible with some combintations of TSRs or device drivers.  Unless memory is really tight, I'd recommend reserving at least 256-512 bytes beyond what one would expect to use, in exchange for Not Having To Worry About It.

In this program, memory is indeed tight: the program uses 64 KiB of memory, and it may need all of it depending on the input. I don't want to waste 512 bytes for a stack if 100 is enough. Refactoring the program to use pointers with different segments would be too much work. (Using a different segment just for the stack is a viable option, but it adds complexity when keeping compatibility with DOS 1.25 or 86-DOS.)

In the SHARE of the MS-DOS v4 free software release from 2024 April, which I just ported to NASM, the stack is relocated to PSP:100h overwriting the tail end of the PSP. And we know that at least 0A0h = 160 bytes of the PSP trail need not be preserved.

@ecm So up to 48 words (96 bytes) stack. What a lovely find :))

@Raffzahn How do you get 96 bytes? I stated that 100h - 60h = 0A0h are free to be used by the stack. 60h = 96 are the length at the PSP start that should be preserved.

What does your program do, does it call DOS or other interrupts (including BIOS, mouse driver, EMM driver, etc)? Also it depends what the other TSRs do, like have they hooked a hardware interrupt like keyboard or timer and run some code in there using your stack. Frankly I don't think there is a specific answer due to all these unknown factors.

@ecm seems like I skipped the 'not' ...

@Justme: My program uses int21h to open a few files, read them, open some other files and write them. It takes the filenames from the command line.

TL;DR: 16 Words (32 Bytes) May Always Do It.

I'm hoping for an answer close to 80 bytes

Yes, 80h bytes seems a pretty secure choice.
Then again, from what I know and can find, even 10h bytes should be sufficient.

Hint#1: Paper Trail
All (simple) examples by MS I know define 64 words (128 Bytes) as default stack. For example see p.302 , p.329, p.337, etc. in the MS-DOS Encyclopedia. Similar in various examples published in the Microsoft Systems Journal (*1).
These values seem to be pretty sufficient for all MS-DOS versions.
Hint#2: DOS Behaviour
The scheduler changes for one of three internal stacks right after
entry, depending on purpose:

IOstack for INT 21h 01h..0Ch
DiskStack for all other INT function
AuxStack for error handling (INT 24 etc.)

In addition any (hardware) interrupt call will use a stack from a stack pool (*2) using a default size of 128 bytes per stack.
Since the whole CPU (8086) CPU state is defined in 12 words (*3), stack need before switching might be as small as 24 Bytes. maybe plus1 or two words for near calls.
Worst case may be if this section is interruptable with some HW  interrupt hitting right before switching to either function stack, thus needing twice the minimum ... rather unlikely I'd say.
Hint#3: DOS Source
Thanks to MS providing sources for MS-DOS 1.25, 2.0 and 4.0, one may simply check there:
DOS 1.25
common DOS entry point is at SAVREGS (line 288 of MADOS.ASM). Here a series of 9 words (18 bytes) is pushed in addition to 3 words already occupied by the INT call (*4) before pointing SS:SP at IOstack or DiskStack.
A total of 12 Words (24 Bytes) is used.
Interrupts are disabled during the whole stack operation, thus DOS 1.25 will never use more than 12 words (*5).
DOS 2.0
DOS 2.0 reorders this a bit with a save_world subroutine (line 237 of MSCODE.ASM) using 1 word of stack for calling (*6) and 9 words for register. Together with 3 words for the (real or emulated) INT it's now
a total of 13 words of stack usage.
DOS 4.0
Here everything got shovelled around even more with our beloved SAVREGS entry point ending up at line 245 of /DOS/DISP.ASM. Now it checks for a few (simple) functions, namely

GET CURRENT PDB
Get Current PSP
SET CURRENT PDB
Set CTRL-C Trapping
Set Printer Flag

which are to be handled using the user stack, but with interrupts disabled. A first glance shows that all of them stay below 9 words (*7). For everything else, it calls the known Save_World (line 444) using again 9 words for
a total of 13 Words of stack usage.
I would think all later DOS versions do as well adhere to the 13 words introduced with DOS 2.0.
Hint#4: Try it Yourself
It should be fairly easy to determinate this number by writing a guard value to the stack and check for either type to see how much it uses before switching. I did a few tests using a simple test program and DOS 3.1, all came up with the same 13 words used.
Conclusion
I'm pretty sure those 13 words (26 Bytes) will be the same in all real mode DOS versions/environments. After all, any increment might break old programs - something MS and especially IBM would try to avoid at all cost.
With 13 words needed, using 10h words is the next nice round number easy to remember even leaving some room for quirks of non-MS implementations.

*1 - I quickly browsed some (German) 1990s MSJ, still shelved in my basement.
*2 - Controlled via STACKS=num,size in CONFIG.SYS
*3 - Well, the total state is 14 registers, but SS and SP have to be stored somewhere else - 8086 isn't a Münchhausen CPU.
*3 - When entering via CALL, the stack is at ENTRY reconfigured as if  coming from an INT.
*4 - When calling DOS via PSP:0 a short 4 instruction sequence is not locked, but any interrupt hitting here is before DOS does any stack handling, thus not creating any risk for mixup.
*5 - Note the nice trick to move the return address at the end of the stack.
*6 - They all use exactly zero words, except CTRL-C handling which needs 1 word.

Some TSRs and device drivers used significantly more than that.  Anything less than 256 bytes would have struck me as rather skimpy back in the day.

The question is not what some random device driver or TSR uses - which runs on a dedicated stack anyway - but what DOS needs when executing a function call (INT 21h).

@Raffzahn To be fair the question did include DOS and interrupts, with a couple of unspecified TSRs installed.

@Justme All TSR and Interrupts programmed to MS spec have to use their own stack, the very same way as DOS does, thus staying within the same limit. Now for TSR not following those guidelines, your guess will be as bad as mine, so no valid reasoning possible.

@Raffzahn: My point was that I recall a number of TSRs back in the day which didn't use their own stack.  They usually kept their stack usage small, but combining them could lead to stack usage beyond the amounts you're suggesting, and so I recall that back in the day programs were recommended to leave extra space when practical to accommodate such things.

Thank you for citing the code evidence and the docs! I'm incined to accept this answer if you add this near the beginning: if all TSRs use their dedicated stack.

@supercat there is no point in arguing with bad behaving software, as by nature they can (and will) overrun any stack provision.

@Raffzahn: If a TSR wouldn't need to store much on the stack while chaining to the previous interrupt handler, using the application stack may be more efficient than having it switch to a stack large enough to supply the needs of whatever it might be chaining to.  I recall that kind of thing being more common with handlers for things like INT 10h mode switching than for things that would hook on asynchronous interrupts, but I don't remember which particular things did or did not use their own stack.
